# Cannot validate ANT 1.9.7 setup

Tags: java, ant, windows-10

I've just installed Java + Ant on a new PC running Windows 10 and while the test "java -version" returns an expected result trying "ant -version" returns several error messages:

```
C:\>ant -version                                                                                                           

C:\>/*                                                                                                                     
'/*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                                 
operable program or batch file.                                                                                            

C:\>Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more                                                     
'Licensed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                           
operable program or batch file.                                                                                            

C:\>contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with                                                  
'contributor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                        
operable program or batch file.                                                                                            

C:\>this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.                                                    
'this' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                               
operable program or batch file.                                                                                            

C:\>The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0                                                
'The' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                                
operable program or batch file.                                                                                            
you was unexpected at this time.                                                                                           

C:\>   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
```

This happens with the very recent version 1.9.7 but I also tried 1.9.6 and get the same results on this PC.
I have configured the following environment variable set:

```
ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Apache\Ant-1.9.7
JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
PATH=%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

Googling any of the error message lines does not retrieve anything interesting. It's not a PATH issue either as the error is indeed returned by Ant and I tried calling the command directly from the "bin" folder as well...

Comment: This looks as if whatever you try to execute as "ant" was not `ant.bat` that is included with the Ant distribution - since Ant's `ant.bat` doesn't contain the license in a `/*` block at all. I'd verify there is no other "ant" on you PATH before %ANT_HOME%\bin and look into `ant.bat` to verify it is the same as https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant.git;a=blob;f=src/script/ant.bat;h=3486e144c48b9bbce7f4a76d6090f7ae39a83670;hb=cecbf5c6bc454d4b28aca0a312b676a82264583f (which is what should be inside the official distribution archives).

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that was it. See my own answer below... Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: yes, I saw it shortly after posting my own commit. Glad it now works for you. The `.cmd` file is the REXX files used for OS/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night sleep I though about investigating the extension execution order defined in %PATHEXT%.

Somehow an installer must have changed it from

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;
```

to

```
PATHEXT=.EXE;.CMD;.COM;.BAT;
```

After resetting %PATHEXT% it's original order my issue was fixed... Correct order below to be clear:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;
```

There are two "ant" executables in the bin folder a ".bat" and a ".cmd". Typing

```
ant.bat -version
```

produces the expected output. Typing

```
ant.cmd -version
```

produces the error I was reporting in my question. Hence changing the extension execution order by processing ".bat" before looking at ".cmd" fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

As per ANT documentation, try below

You can check the basic installation with opening a new shell and typing ant. You should get a message like this

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

So Ant works. This message is there because you need to write an individual buildfile for your project.

With a ant -version you should get an output like

```
  Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
```

If this does not work ensure your environment variables are set right. They must resolve to:

```
 required: %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant.bat
 optional: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
 required: %PATH%=...maybe-other-entries...;%ANT_HOME%\bin;...maybe-other-entries...
```

for more information [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks @murali, unfortunately your answer refers to parts of the documentation I did already mentioned in my question as being "cleared" (please re-read the section on environment variables in my question). Thanks for trying to help though.